# Why $S^1$ does not homeomorphic to $[0, 1)$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, continuity

The map $f:[0,1)\to S^1$  given by $f(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ is a continuous bijection.
However since $S^1$ is compact and  $[0,1)$ is not compact, $f$ can not be a homeomorphism.
For any $z\in S^1,$ we have $f^{-1}(z)=\dfrac{\log(z)}{2\pi i}.$ I suppose $f^{-1}:S^1\to[0,1)$ is not continuous.
But I could not explain it precisely. 
How can this happen?

Since $S^1$ not homeomorphic to $[0,1),$ is it homeomorphic to $[0,1]$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712796/let-c-be-a-circle-show-that-the-only-subset-of-c-homeomorphic-to-a-circle-is-c?rq=1

Comment: No, you can remove a point from $[0,1]$ to get two connected components, but can't do the same with $S^1$.

Comment: Hint: What are open sets containing $0$ on the interval vs. the open sets containing $\exp(0)$ on the circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence $x_n = f(1 - \frac{1}{n})$. On the circle, $x_n = e^{2\pi i - \frac{2 \pi i}{n}} \to e^{2\pi i} = 1 + 0i$ (which is identified with the point $(1,0)$ on the plane). However, $f^{-1}(x_n) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ has no limit in $[0,1)$ and in particular we don't have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{-1}(x_n) = f^{-1}(1) = 0$ as the limit doesn't even exist!

The circle $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. You can see that by noticing that if you remove any point from $S^1$, you are left with a connected space while if you remove any point that is not equal to $0,1$ from $[0,1]$, you get a disconnected space. Thus, $S^1$ and $[0,1]$ cannot be homeomorphic. If this is the first time you see such an argument, I really recommend writing down explicitly all the details (assume that there exists a homeomorphism $f \colon S^1 \rightarrow [0,1]$, show that $f|_{S^1 \setminus \{ f^{-1}(1/2) \}}$ must be a homeomorphism between ${S^1 \setminus \{ f^{-1}(1/2)}$ and $[0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1]$ and show that this is not possible).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But as I think we can bend $[0, 1)$ continuously to obtain $S^1.$ So, why can not we reverse it?

Comment: Well, can you bend $S^1$ continuously into $[0,1)$ without "tearing up" anything?

Comment: Cool. I got it. Is it means $\log$ function is not continuous at $1+0i$?

Comment: @Nil: Yep, you cannot define a $\log$ function that will be continuous on the whole of $S^1$. One might think that maybe $\log$ won't work but something else will but the topological argument ($S^1$ is compact, $[0,1)$ is not) shows that no function can be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

With the topology induced by $\Bbb R$, the spaces $\Bbb S^1$ and $[0,1[$ aren't homeomorphic. But if you change the topology on the set $[0,1[$, the function $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$ become an homeomorphism. Precisely, endowed $[0,1[$ with a coarser topology $\tau$ whose open set are:
$U=(\epsilon, 1-\delta) \quad \epsilon, \delta >0$, and $U=[0, \epsilon[\cup ]1-\delta, 1[$.

Comment: How can we build such a topology? Where did you get that intuition to describe the open sets in this new topology?

Comment: You obtain this topology from the one induced by $\Bbb R$ removing open subset ( with respect to the subspace topology ) of the form $[0,\epsilon[$, and $]1-\delta,1[$.

Comment: According to your argument, we can make a homeomorphism by using a bijection and choosing a suitable topology on the domain. Am I correct? ☺