# Describe the quotient space that results from the partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into the equivalence classes on $\mathbb{R}$ given by $x-y\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

> Consider the equivalence relation defined in $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $x \sim y$ if $x-y\in \mathbb{Z}$.
> Describe the quotient space that results  from the partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into the equivalence classes result from the equivalence relation.

First assume that $\sim$ is a relation of equivalence, following tha definition of class of equivalence
$[x]=\lbrace y\in \mathbb{R}:x \sim y\rbrace = \lbrace x-n:n\in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ this for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$
For find the quotient space i need to know the open sets in the quotient space, fix $[x]\in \mathbb{R/ \sim}$ then $p^{-1}([x])$ where $p:\mathbb{R}  \longrightarrow \mathbb{R/ \sim}$ is just
$p^{-1}([x])=\lbrace y\in \mathbb{R}:p(y)\in [x]\rbrace= \lbrace x-n:n\in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ therefore since $<\mathbb{Z}>=\mathbb{Z}$ we can change of representant of the class and claim that the quotient is homeomorphic to the $[0,1)$ but i can prove it.
Someone that can give me a proof or contraexample, any help wasvery useful.

Comment: Yep. The set of reals having the same fractional part is an element of the quotient. The classes are all the real numbers between 0 and 1 (1 excluded). I don't get why $n$ must be big, tho...

Comment: That’s almost right, but not quite: $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ is open in $[0,1)$, but the corresponding set in $\Bbb R$ is not open. $\Bbb R/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$, the unit circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotient space can be naturally identified with $[0,1)$, true, but not as a group and not as a topological space. The quotient space is $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, which is isomorphic (as a group) and homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$. You can map from $[0,1)$ via $t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$, and this actually gives you the quotient map from $\mathbb R$ that induces the topology.

If you're not looking for any kind of structure-preserving map, then identifying it with $[0,1)$ is easy and fine. But you mention isomorphism, for which $[0,1)$ would not be appropriate algebraically or topologically.

Comment: +1. According to his tags, he should be looking at the quotient topology. I had a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988045/why-s1-does-not-homeomorphic-to-0-1) while ago.

Comment: I Confused a little  bit with the quotient spaces in topology and quotient spaces in Groups, I was Refering to the quotient as topological  space, in it case how can i see that is homeomorpic to $S^{1}$ using the map of $\mathbb{R/\simeq} \longrightarrow S_{1}$

Comment: As I explain the class of $x\in \mathbb{R} $ is $[x]= \lbrace x-n:n\in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ and I had the problem seeing wich clasess are open in the quotient topology

Comment: @Brien $e^{2\pi i t} $ is the quotient map.